# POP3 commands in TCP sampler in Jmeter

Tags: tcp, jmeter, pop3

Using TCP sampler in Jmeter, I am connected successfully with a pop3 server and set "USER username" as text to send it works and server response over to send the second command.
Can any help me to send the second command "PASS password" one TCP sampler with multiple commands or need to add more TCP sampler for a single command?

Comment: You should be using [tag:javamail] instead of trying to roll your own mail agent.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will be able to do this using JMeter's TCP Sampler, you can try [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) plugin which has option to keep the connection open so you will be able to pass multiple commands within the same TCP session. The HTTP Raw Request sampler can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

---

However I'm under impression that you're doing something weird. Connecting to POP3 server via telnet is not something the majority of users will do and if you need to load test an email server you should be simulating user actions with 100% accuracy. JMeter comes with [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) which can be used for fetching messages using POP3 or IMAP protocols which is much closer to real email clients and much easier to implement. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) for more information if needed